# Retrieving Data From two tables that are associated with a forign key in CakePhp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join, inner-join

I have two tables named login and userDetail

```
                        Login

                        login_id
                        uname
                        pswd
                        userdetail_id
```

and

```
                       userdetails

                          userdetail_id
                          name
                          address
                          email
```

the login table contain userdetails_id in the userDetail table. i want to get all data from Login table and userDetail table and save it to a variable
if anyone knows, please answer me......

Comment: Do you mean how to do a JOIN query to get all the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your table structure must be as below.

```
logins Table.
  Id auto_increment
  username
  password
```

```
userDetails Table.
  Id auto_increment
  user_id
  name
  address
  etc...
```

Now model for each table would be.

**Login**

```
<?php
class Login extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'User';

    var $hasMany = array
    (
        'UserDetail' => array
        (
            'className' => 'UserDetail',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
}
?>
```

**UserDetail**

```
<?php
class UserDetail extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'UserDetail';

    var $belongsTo = array
    (
        'User' => array
        (
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => ''
        )
}
?>
```

And finally in controller where you need to fetch login detail.

`$login_detail = $this->Login->find('all');`

You will see userDetail table records in resulting `$login_detail`.
use

```
pr($login_detail);
```

in controller to see it in action.

Cheers.
Feel Free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure [ContainableBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) has been enabled. After that you can use following query:

```
$login = $this->Login->find('first', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Userdetail.userdetail_id'
        'Userdetail.name',
        'Userdetail.address',
        'Userdetail.email'
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Login.login_id'
        'Login.uname',
        'Login.pswd'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Login.login_id' => 1
    )
));
```

Answer (score -1):

The query for this task would be:

```
SELECT Login.*, name,address,email
        FROM Login JOIN userdetails
        ON Login.userdetail_id=userdetails.userdetail_id
```

The results of this query could be saved to variables by looping in cakephp.

Comment: why not to follow cakephp convention.??? if we don't wanna use cakephp rules then no need to use it corePHP works fine too for this...isn't it...dont take this personally but i just don't like to use straight queries while cake has so many ways to achieve this kind of tasks...